# java.lang.NullPointerException when merging output files

Tags: hive, orc, apache-tez

I have a table with 3 partition columns

```
create table tn(
col1 string,
etc...
)
partitioned by (
time_key date,
region string,
city string
)
stored as orc
tblproperties ("orc.compress"="ZLIB");
```

City partition can have from a few mb to a few hundred mb. I'm trying to optimize storage so all small files are merged into a single one equal to a block size of 128mb, and bigger files are split accordingly.

Source table has 200 files around 150 mb each. It's not partitioned.

I do a simple insert statement for that.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE tn PARTITION (time_key, region, city) 
SELECT * FROM source_tn;
```

With the following settings and get this error `NullPointerException`.

```
set hive.merge.tezfiles=true;
set hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=128000000;
set hive.merge.size.per.task=128000000;
set hive.merge.orcfile.stripe.level=true;
set hive.auto.convert.join=false;
```

If I try the insert without these settings it works out fine, so there isn't anything wrong with the data. The problem in this case is each `city` subpartition holds around 200 files. With the total amount of files in the `time_key` partiton reaching 30-40 thousands.

What's the problem and what can I do?

I'm using hive tez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting this to false helped.

```
set hive.merge.orcfile.stripe.level=false;
```